# How to map path of Image in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Suppose There is image in **IMAGE** folder in our project it is hosted on www.abc.com

If I have to access image then I write image path

img src="www.abc.com/images/imagename.jpg" alt=""

I have seen many times that image path shows on sub domain like **www.static.abc.com**

img src="www.static.abc.com/imagename.jpg" alt=""

but **IMAGE** folder is  present inside  www.abc.com

How is It possible ?

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is first get root path

```
  var path = getRootPath();
```

then append your image folder path to var path

hope this will help you